# add and use remote repositories in Apache Archiva

Tags: apache, maven, jboss, repository, archiva

Well, I researched how to configure Apache Maven to use Apache Archiva as a source of artifacts and how to configure Apache Archiva to use other external repositories, however, do not know why but it is not working. I need your help please.

**Research I did to test the configured remote repository, he found the library was looking for, but in the remote repository that had added more versions:**

http://s7.postimg.org/u852evm3f/Fire_Shot_Screen_Capture_012_Apache_Archiva.png

The same library that researched the remote repository JBoss (I set):
https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/

I used the information from the repository jboss this page to configure a remote repository in Apache Archiva: "community.jboss.org/en/build/blog/2011/06/01/blocking-repositoryjbossorgmaven2".

Configuration repository:
"s8.postimg.org/dr11j7bdx/Fire_Shot_Screen_Capture_006_Apache_Archiva.png"

Configuring Proxy connections:
"s14.postimg.org/st5yvds0h/Fire_Shot_Screen_Capture_013_Apache_Archiva.png"

Maven settings.xml configured to use Apache Archiva:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more contributor 
    license agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed with this work for additional 
    information regarding copyright ownership. The ASF licenses this file to 
    you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use 
    this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of 
    the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Unless required 
    by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the 
    License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS 
    OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific 
    language governing permissions and limitations under the License. -->

<!-- | This is the configuration file for Maven. It can be specified at two 
    levels: | | 1. User Level. This settings.xml file provides configuration 
    for a single user, | and is normally provided in ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml. 
    | | NOTE: This location can be overridden with the CLI option: | | -s /path/to/user/settings.xml 
    | | 2. Global Level. This settings.xml file provides configuration for all 
    Maven | users on a machine (assuming they're all using the same Maven | installation). 
    It's normally provided in | ${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml. | | NOTE: This 
    location can be overridden with the CLI option: | | -gs /path/to/global/settings.xml 
    | | The sections in this sample file are intended to give you a running start 
    at | getting the most out of your Maven installation. Where appropriate, 
    the default | values (values used when the setting is not specified) are 
    provided. | | -->
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <!-- localRepository | The path to the local repository maven will use to 
        store artifacts. | | Default: ${user.home}/.m2/repository <localRepository>/path/to/local/repo</localRepository> -->

    <!-- interactiveMode | This will determine whether maven prompts you when 
        it needs input. If set to false, | maven will use a sensible default value, 
        perhaps based on some other setting, for | the parameter in question. | | 
        Default: true <interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode> -->

    <!-- offline | Determines whether maven should attempt to connect to the 
        network when executing a build. | This will have an effect on artifact downloads, 
        artifact deployment, and others. | | Default: false <offline>false</offline> -->

    <!-- pluginGroups | This is a list of additional group identifiers that 
        will be searched when resolving plugins by their prefix, i.e. | when invoking 
        a command line like "mvn prefix:goal". Maven will automatically add the group 
        identifiers | "org.apache.maven.plugins" and "org.codehaus.mojo" if these 
        are not already contained in the list. | -->
    <pluginGroups>
        <!-- pluginGroup | Specifies a further group identifier to use for plugin 
            lookup. <pluginGroup>com.your.plugins</pluginGroup> -->
    </pluginGroups>

    <!-- proxies | This is a list of proxies which can be used on this machine 
        to connect to the network. | Unless otherwise specified (by system property 
        or command-line switch), the first proxy | specification in this list marked 
        as active will be used. | -->
    <proxies>
        <!-- proxy | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the 
            network. | <proxy> <id>optional</id> <active>true</active> <protocol>http</protocol> 
            <username>proxyuser</username> <password>proxypass</password> <host>proxy.host.net</host> 
            <port>80</port> <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts> </proxy> -->
    </proxies>

    <!-- servers | This is a list of authentication profiles, keyed by the server-id 
        used within the system. | Authentication profiles can be used whenever maven 
        must make a connection to a remote server. | -->
    <servers>
        <!-- server | Specifies the authentication information to use when connecting 
            to a particular server, identified by | a unique name within the system (referred 
            to by the 'id' attribute below). | | NOTE: You should either specify username/password 
            OR privateKey/passphrase, since these pairings are | used together. | <server> 
            <id>deploymentRepo</id> <username>repouser</username> <password>repopwd</password> 
            </server> -->

        <!-- Another sample, using keys to authenticate. <server> <id>siteServer</id> 
            <privateKey>/path/to/private/key</privateKey> <passphrase>optional; leave 
            empty if not used.</passphrase> </server> -->
    </servers>

    <!-- mirrors | This is a list of mirrors to be used in downloading artifacts 
        from remote repositories. | | It works like this: a POM may declare a repository 
        to use in resolving certain artifacts. | However, this repository may have 
        problems with heavy traffic at times, so people have mirrored | it to several 
        places. | | That repository definition will have a unique id, so we can create 
        a mirror reference for that | repository, to be used as an alternate download 
        site. The mirror site will be the preferred | server for that repository. 
        | -->
    <mirrors>
        <!-- mirror | Specifies a repository mirror site to use instead of a given 
            repository. The repository that | this mirror serves has an ID that matches 
            the mirrorOf element of this mirror. IDs are used | for inheritance and direct 
            lookup purposes, and must be unique across the set of mirrors. | <mirror> 
            <id>mirrorId</id> <mirrorOf>repositoryId</mirrorOf> <name>Human Readable 
            Name for this Mirror.</name> <url>http://my.repository.com/repo/path</url> 
            </mirror> -->
        <mirror>
            <id>internal</id>
            <name>Archiva Managed Internal Repository</name>
            <url>http://localhost:8081/archiva/repository/internal</url>
            <mirrorOf>external:*</mirrorOf>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>

    <!-- profiles | This is a list of profiles which can be activated in a variety 
        of ways, and which can modify | the build process. Profiles provided in the 
        settings.xml are intended to provide local machine- | specific paths and 
        repository locations which allow the build to work in the local environment. 
        | | For example, if you have an integration testing plugin - like cactus 
        - that needs to know where | your Tomcat instance is installed, you can provide 
        a variable here such that the variable is | dereferenced during the build 
        process to configure the cactus plugin. | | As noted above, profiles can 
        be activated in a variety of ways. One way - the activeProfiles | section 
        of this document (settings.xml) - will be discussed later. Another way essentially 
        | relies on the detection of a system property, either matching a particular 
        value for the property, | or merely testing its existence. Profiles can also 
        be activated by JDK version prefix, where a | value of '1.4' might activate 
        a profile when the build is executed on a JDK version of '1.4.2_07'. | Finally, 
        the list of active profiles can be specified directly from the command line. 
        | | NOTE: For profiles defined in the settings.xml, you are restricted to 
        specifying only artifact | repositories, plugin repositories, and free-form 
        properties to be used as configuration | variables for plugins in the POM. 
        | | -->
    <profiles>
        <!-- profile | Specifies a set of introductions to the build process, to 
            be activated using one or more of the | mechanisms described above. For inheritance 
            purposes, and to activate profiles via <activatedProfiles/> | or the command 
            line, profiles have to have an ID that is unique. | | An encouraged best 
            practice for profile identification is to use a consistent naming convention 
            | for profiles, such as 'env-dev', 'env-test', 'env-production', 'user-jdcasey', 
            'user-brett', etc. | This will make it more intuitive to understand what 
            the set of introduced profiles is attempting | to accomplish, particularly 
            when you only have a list of profile id's for debug. | | This profile example 
            uses the JDK version to trigger activation, and provides a JDK-specific repo. 
            <profile> <id>jdk-1.4</id> <activation> <jdk>1.4</jdk> </activation> <repositories> 
            <repository> <id>jdk14</id> <name>Repository for JDK 1.4 builds</name> <url>http://www.myhost.com/maven/jdk14</url> 
            <layout>default</layout> <snapshotPolicy>always</snapshotPolicy> </repository> 
            </repositories> </profile> -->

        <!-- | Here is another profile, activated by the system property 'target-env' 
            with a value of 'dev', | which provides a specific path to the Tomcat instance. 
            To use this, your plugin configuration | might hypothetically look like: 
            | | ... | <plugin> | <groupId>org.myco.myplugins</groupId> | <artifactId>myplugin</artifactId> 
            | | <configuration> | <tomcatLocation>${tomcatPath}</tomcatLocation> | </configuration> 
            | </plugin> | ... | | NOTE: If you just wanted to inject this configuration 
            whenever someone set 'target-env' to | anything, you could just leave off 
            the <value/> inside the activation-property. | <profile> <id>env-dev</id> 
            <activation> <property> <name>target-env</name> <value>dev</value> </property> 
            </activation> <properties> <tomcatPath>/path/to/tomcat/instance</tomcatPath> 
            </properties> </profile> -->
    </profiles>

    <!-- activeProfiles | List of profiles that are active for all builds. | 
        <activeProfiles> <activeProfile>alwaysActiveProfile</activeProfile> <activeProfile>anotherAlwaysActiveProfile</activeProfile> 
        </activeProfiles> -->
</settings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question - but it sounds like you're expecting it to list all the versions in the remote repository, before you've attempted to use them. Currently Archiva only displays those that it has already proxied, and future requested artifacts will be downloaded and added there automatically.

Comment: hmm mean I have to "use" the version it gives me until he seeks the other versions of the remote repository?
But this version is that he returned me the Maven Central repository, not the repository of JBoss has a newer version

Comment: I'm sorry, my english is crap. You mean I have to use version 1.8.0 until the Archiva is willing to seek other releases in Jboss (1.8.2, 1.8.3, ...) repository?

Answer (score 0):

note last version of Archiva can download remote index so all versions can be displayed in search results.

Comment: The Archiva 1.4-M4 has a feature that is "Index Scanning", but I already tried that several times and did not work the day after I scanned the indexes again, researched again and did not work again. I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: what is your problem exactly? If you don't see all versions from remote. You must use last 1.4-M4 which can download index from remote repositories as it all versions from remote will be displayed in search but not in browsing!

Comment: Yes, i'm using the version 1.4-M4, i've tried download the index, 
but it was not presented in the survey all versions, only the version 1.8.0